# Retrieve/ Access Bot Response in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: python, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have a bot made using Microsoft Bot Framework using Python. Now, I am able to capture user input using turn_context.activity.text not able to figure out -- How to capture bot response?

Please help?

Comment: First go through the basic  documentation of chatbot flow then you will come to know the process.

Comment: You can get started by referring to the [botbuilder samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: But, are You using QnA or what exactly to answer the user question ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python

Using the same turn context you used to get the text, you can use it to send a reply.

```
await turn_context.send_activity("Welcome!")
```

You would need to use the Bot Emulator or side-load the bot in MS Teams to test/see the response.

Comment: The bot responds differently  depending on the question asked. How can I capture that? I mean that is a dynamic thing. But here its only "Welcome"